# .htaccess - rewrite one uri, but all redirected to HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am really struggling to get .htaccess correct. I basically want to convert

product.php?sku=M1234 for example to display as M1234.php and to be able to type ../M1234.php to take to perform that operation. I also want all pages on the website to be HTTPS.

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,N]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /products/product.php?product_id=$1 [L]
```

With no success. Any advice would be most appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: 1. remove `N`-flag since it's loopable. 2. that regex `^([^/]*)\.html$` does match `/M1234.html`, but this `([^/]*)\.html$` corresponds also to `/any/M1234.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /products/product.php?sku=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

This will use `website.com/test` to request `website.com/products/product.php?sku=test`